# Building Binary Tree from InOrder and PostOrder in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

I know that there are other topics with this question. I'm just trying to understand what is wrong with my solution.

```
treeFromInOrderPostOrder(inorder, postorder) {

        const helper = (inO, postO, start, end, index) => {
            if(start > end) return null;

            const node = new TreeNode(postO[index]);
            
            const i = inO.indexOf(node.val);

            // no children
            if(start === end)   return node;

            // right subtree
            node.right = helper(inO, postO, i+1, end, index--);
            // left subtree
            node.left = helper(inO, postO, start, i-1, index--);

            return node;
        }

        const size = inorder.length-1;
        return helper(inorder, postorder, 0, size, size);
    }
```

It returns: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. It happens on the line: `node.right = helper(inO, postO, i+1, end, index--);`

I'm trying with the inputs:
`PostOrder: [2,4,3,6,9,10,5]`
`InOrder: [2,3,4,5,6,9,10]`

TreeNode class:

```
module.exports = class TreeNode {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So `TreeNode()` has some async code then? Perhaps there's a loop in there too?

Comment: I just added the TreeNode() class. It is just a constructor for the Node